# Suggested Edit - Author input?

Tags: feature-request

Someone suggested an edit to an answer I wrote recently. The edit was reviewed and rejected on grounds I as the author would have been best situated to assess.

It seems like a good idea for the OP to be notified of suggested edits and have a say - especially since they have authority to make the edits anyway.

Comment: You can always rollback an edit you dislike. What would happen if everyone were to be notified that somebody wanted to fix a typo? And if the OP doesn't reply? How long should someone wait before going ahead and fixing poor grammar, typos, repairing broken links, improving formatting, citing resources etc. etc.?

Comment: I'm not saying wait for the OP. I'm saying notify the OP and then continue as before. This allows OP input, if exercised, where they know best, say on questions of intent. I take your point about grammar etc. Maybe those able to review edits can manually trigger the notification where appropriate or the site can trigger a notification only when not tagged with certain tags, or

Comment: @GetzelR Huh. I do get notified when someone edits my question or answer. Or am I misremembering?

Comment: @DanBron yes, I have been notified in the past too, but if you're not in front of your PC, the edit, if approved, passes through regardless. Hence my above comment. Perhaps this is a *bug*?

Answer (score 2):

The Stack Exchange model relies on community participation to make questions and answers more helpful. People can up vote, down vote, flag, comment, vote to close, delete, and with enough reputation, edit. Good edits are encouraged with reputation and badges.

The fact is that OP's *are* notified and can roll back (if you weren't, you can address this as a bug.) If you're feeling proprietary about your posts, it might make this model less than ideal for you.

I don't see this as a problem.

Comment: I did see a passive notification in the site inbox, but only when I came back and it was already after the fact. I wasn't feeling proprietary - to the contrary, I felt that the edit was a clarification and it was shot down on grounds of intent. I ended up included a variation of it myself, which was accepted. The process just struck me as odd and I thought I'd suggest an improvement.

Comment: In the SE model, the that's not an improvement.

Comment: Rightfully rejected, then.